# My site goes to maintenance mode spontaneously

Tags: system

My site goes to maintenance mode spontaneously almost every day. I am advised by users.

Everything works fine when I put it out of maintenance mode.

Any explanation is welcome

(Drupal 7.59 / Civicrm 5.4.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error came from the Backup & Migrate Module : I had an error when I wanted to access the "Schedule" folder.
When I unstalled the Module, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with the Backup and Migrate module where this would happen. There is a setting to put into maintenance mode while the backup is running. But the backup would error out and never turn off maintenance mode.

Answer (score 1):

Can be a number of reasons with Drupal, I would imagine it's a probably on the Drupal side and not Civicrm though.

There could be something doing it in a module etc. etc, have to look at error log around the time it switches into maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Reports -> check the dblog (Recent Log Messages) and see if you can find out what and when is putting your site into maintenance mode.

Comment: dblog (https://xxx.com/admin/reports/dblog) does not show any item regarding maintenance (even when I personnaly change the maintenance mode).